# Call javascript function programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

With `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]` method I get, with a GET request, a list of records from html page.

The records are paged at intervals of 20. To get the pages following the first, a function is called

```
javascript: GoToPagina (n)
```

where `n` is the number of page.

How can I call the function programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `UIWebView` to do what you are asking about, as that is the only thing that can execute javascript on iOS.  You can load it up with the URL in question, and when it's done loading:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoToPagina(%d), pageNum]];
```

---

However, in order to do it with `NSURLConnection` directly, you can't use JS.  Instead, forgure out what URL the `GoToPagina(n)` function gets its data from and call that directly with another `NSURLConnection`.

If all you want is the data and you don't want to show any webview at all, then this is more likely what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it depends on what context you're calling it from. If you've imported the script that contains the function or it's on the page you're working with, you can just call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someRandomNumber = 5;
GoToPagina(someRandomNumber);
</script>
```

But who knows when you want to call it, or from what context, or under which conditions, etc.

( not us, because you didn't specify ;) )